# How to edit number after hide keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have this problem on jetpack compose kotlin, I have this code
https://gist.github.com/alphadotwork/c0f1963ab92d8926640f4c405155a402

I have a problem here, everything works fine, but when I hide the keyboard and then try to rewrite any of the numbers I cant edit them, any ideas of hhow to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and it is working as expected. I am able to edit the pin after hiding the keyboard ([Testing GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/apwCPMOVaniz5FcHRN/giphy.gif)). Although in your code the problem seems to allow to add more digits after entering the maximum numbers.

You can add restrictions on `onValueChange`  like this. It will restrict entering the number up to **digitCount**.

```kotlin
if (it.length <= digitCount) {
  onPinTextChange.invoke(it)
}
```

Just FYI - You can check out [SSComposeOTPPinView](https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSComposeOTPPinView) created by us which does the same thing with compose.